# Clem never attacks

Tags: technical-issues, warframe

When doing the mission "A Man of Few Words", and Clem's subsequent weekly mission, Clem never attacks; he just follows me around and ignores all enemies even as they eat his face.  This behavior persists even after closing and re-opening the game.

I've looked online and couldn't find any discussions about the issue-- is there anything further I can do to isolate or resolve this problem?

Comment: What's up with the downvote?  I put forth research effort, and I think the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

This should be adressed to the Bug Reports session of the [official warframe forums](https://forums.warframe.com/) in the appropriate platform (PC/XBOX/PS4). If you are able to record the error, it will futher provide evidence for them to check out your bug.

From personal experience, clem was working fine for the last weeks, but I haven't acquired him recently to experiment, so you might want to record videos showing the failure!

edit: I can now attest clem is NOT attacking and this should be reported in the bug report zone!